# Oracel user defined function always returns NULL

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write UDF in oracle the returns some based on the difference between a supplied date and today. Below is my code

```
SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE('01.01.2017') FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_AGE_RANGE(
    SAP_DATE IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  ResultVar VARCHAR2(255);
    TheDate DATE;
    TheDiff NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    --convert to date
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN SAP_DATE = '00.00.0000'
        THEN NULL
        ELSE to_date(SAP_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy')
      END
    INTO TheDate
    FROM DUAL;
    --workout date difference
    SELECT sysdate - TheDate
    INTO TheDiff
    FROM DUAL;
    --set the frequency
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN TheDiff < -180
        THEN '>6 Months'
        WHEN TheDiff < -90
        THEN '3-6 Months'
        WHEN TheDiff < 0
        THEN '<3 Months'
      END
    INTO ResultVar
    FROM DUAL;
    RETURN(ResultVar);
  END;
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code

`(sysdate - TheDate)` is positive so

```
SELECT


CASE
    WHEN TheDiff < -180
    THEN '>6 Months'
    WHEN TheDiff < -90
    THEN '3-6 Months'
    WHEN TheDiff < 0
    THEN '<3 Months'
  END
INTO ResultVar
FROM DUAL;
```

always will return null

change last part of your code  to this

```
SELECT


    CASE
        WHEN TheDiff > -180
        THEN '>6 Months'
        WHEN TheDiff > -90
        THEN '3-6 Months'
        WHEN TheDiff > 0
        THEN '<3 Months'
      END
    INTO ResultVar
    FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Good observation about the (sysdate - TheDate) being positive for the sample. Because short circuit evaluation is being performed, the value for `SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE('01.02.2017') FROM DUAL;` will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Vecchiasignora's answer is correct related to the logic of your code.  However, I want to add that to run a case statement, you don't need SQL, you can use the construct in PL/SQL as well.  This simplifies your code a bit.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_AGE_RANGE(
        SAP_DATE IN VARCHAR2 )
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      ResultVar VARCHAR2(255);
        TheDate DATE;
        TheDiff NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        --convert to date
         CASE
            WHEN SAP_DATE = '00.00.0000' THEN NULL;
            ELSE TheDate := to_date(SAP_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy');
          END CASE;

        --workout date difference
        TheDiff :=  sysdate - TheDate;

        --set the frequency
          CASE
            WHEN TheDiff > 180 THEN ResultVar := '>6 Months';
            WHEN TheDiff > 90  THEN ResultVar := '3-6 Months';
            WHEN TheDiff > 0   THEN ResultVar := '<3 Months';
          END CASE;

        RETURN(ResultVar);
      END;
```

Comment: yes, and  don't use sql environment if you can write it in pl/sql , it will be more faster

Comment: @Vecchiasignora - that is good advice in this case as we are already in the PL/SQL engine. However, it may confuse people who have heard the 'rule' that if it can de done in SQL you should do so as it is likely to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure your case statement covers your sample set**

First, the salient values of `SAP_DATE` appear to be when the `SYSDATE` is greater than `SAP_DATE`.

For example, the age of the `SAP_DATE` should be 6 months when we have a November 1st, 2016 date.

When the `SAP_DATE` is greater than the current date, no `ResultVar` has been defined.  I will call this 'Current'.

When using case statements in Oracle, it is important to consider that short circuit evaluations are being performed, thus the first boolean expression which is true will be the resulting value assigned to `ResultVar`.

Here is my modification:

```
SCOTT@dev>set echo on;
SCOTT@dev>CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_AGE_RANGE(
  2      SAP_DATE IN VARCHAR2 )
  3    RETURN VARCHAR2
  4  IS
  5    ResultVar VARCHAR2(255);
  6      TheDate DATE;
  7      TheDiff NUMBER;
  8    BEGIN
  9      --convert to date
 10      SELECT
 11        CASE
 12          WHEN SAP_DATE = '00.00.0000'
 13          THEN NULL
 14          ELSE to_date(SAP_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy')
 15        END
 16      INTO TheDate
 17      FROM DUAL;
 18      --workout date difference
 19      SELECT sysdate - TheDate
 20      INTO TheDiff
 21      FROM DUAL;
 22      --set the frequency
 23      SELECT
 24        CASE
 25          WHEN TheDiff > 180
 26          THEN '>6 Months'
 27          WHEN TheDiff > 90
 28          THEN '3-6 Months'
 29          WHEN TheDiff > 0
 30          THEN '<3 Months'
 31          WHEN TheDiff <= 0
 32          THEN  'Current'
 33          ELSE NULL
 34        END
 35      INTO ResultVar
 36      FROM DUAL;
 37      RETURN(ResultVar);
 38    END;
 39  /

Function FN_AGE_RANGE compiled

SCOTT@dev>---sample data
SCOTT@dev>-- > 6 months
SCOTT@dev>SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE('01.11.2016') FROM DUAL;
FN_AGE_RANGE('01.11.2016')
>6 Months


SCOTT@dev>-- > 3 months
SCOTT@dev>SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE('01.02.2017') FROM DUAL;
FN_AGE_RANGE('01.02.2017')
3-6 Months


SCOTT@dev>SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE('01.07.2017') FROM DUAL;
FN_AGE_RANGE('01.07.2017')
Current


SCOTT@dev>--> NULL
SCOTT@dev>SELECT FN_AGE_RANGE(NULL) FROM DUAL;
FN_AGE_RANGE(NULL)
```